# Corrupted machine, unable to find "Recover Lost license"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-license-manager

My machine I use for Arc Desktop recently... crashed. I am trying to authorize my license on a new machine. This is a ArcGIS Desktop for Personal Use license (single use). Below is a screenshot of the licensing tab (with no option to recover lost licenses). Any help?

[image: Licensing tab]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me in the past, I had to contact ESRI support and ask them to recover it.

There is no way to recall it from that machine, as you would need to be able to run the license administrator on it.